# Automotive transients: which rail goes how?

Tags: automotive, transient

Presumably it would depend on each transient

http://www.sft-lab.com.cn/uploads/ISO_16750-2-2010.pdf
http://sft-lab.com/uploads/ISO7637-2-2011.pdf

Or is there a more general rule - i.e. when a -100V transient arrives is it the +12V rail going to -88V, or the GND rail going +112V, or something in between ?

---

**Clarification attempt**:

Regular operation, Moment t1:

```
V_in(X,t1) = 13.5V
V_gnd(Y,t1) = 0V
```

-100V Transient arrives, Peak Moment t2:

```
V_in(X,t2) - V_in(X,t1) = delta_V_in
V_gnd(Y,t2) - V_gnd(Y,t2) = delta_V_gnd
```

For one fixed point on the wires (both 12V and GND are wired), specifically the point at which the wires end into a connector block, what would the `delta_V_gnd` and `delta_V_in` be ?

Comment: What do you mean "which rail"? Does you equipment have multiple supplies or--?

Comment: @TimWilliams I mean +12V or GND lines

Comment: The point at which your equipment connects to GND is immutably 0 volts and, everything that comes downstream is relative to that 0 volts.

Comment: Yes, there are two ways to look at it: either 1. everything is common ground on a low-impedance plane (typical of actual automotive use-cases, where the frame/chassis is used as ground return), or 2. common mode voltages are completely out of scope of these standards and you are only concerned with the voltage drop at the device inlet (whether a single wire (with chassis return) or two wire connector). The relative voltages are given by the waveform diagrams; some are relative to U_A, some absolute.

Answer (score 0):

**Voltage is a two point entity.** Saying that the voltage on one rail is changing is meaningless. What is called zero volts is arbitrary.

If a meter’s black probe is placed on the car chassis then and the red probe is placed on the 12V rail, then a -100V transient from rail to chassis will be measured as -88V.

If the probes were reversed the measurement would be +88V.

If the transient occurred from chassis to earth then the previous measurements would be 12V and -12V respectively, even though the chassis and rail both changed by -100V **relative to earth**.
The voltage measured from earth to chassis or rail would be undefined, unless a defined impedance exists from chassis to earth, bypassing the tires.
In this case if the black probe is placed on earth, then the chassis will measure-100V. The rail will measure -88V.

Voltage cannot arrive at one point. It always appears between two points due to the arrival of current in the form of charge flow or displacement current developing a voltage across local impedance.